# Laptop: close lid, turn screen of but keep RDP enabled (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: power-management, screensaver, rdp, lid

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on an old laptop.
From windows, I can connect with the RDP-protocol, no problem.
To save some energy: I want to have my screen blank, but in that case, I can NOT connect anymore with RDP.
More: I want to close the lid of my laptop, turn the screen off, but keep RDP-connection enabled...

I already tried to edit

```
nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

and configured

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

RDP works, as long as long as screen does not turn blank. But in that case, screen is still consuming power....

So question: how can I turn my laptop in a "headless" (RDP-)server....

kind regards,
Bart Plessers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog)