# Maintaining RDP connection to Ubuntu after Ubuntu Screen times out (goes black)

Tags: remote-desktop

So, I have just installed Ubuntu 22.10 on an older machine on my network.
I have enabled RDP and remote control on it, and am successfully able to RDP into it from my Windows 11 box with no issues.
That is, however, until the Ubuntu box times out and either goes into lock mode, or the screen turns off; both default settings.  Once that happens, the RDP session disconnects and I have to walk over to the Ubuntu box and log back in.
So, I was able to disable the auto-lock as well as the screen-black function so that I can RDP into it whenever I want.
However, I really don't want this box just sitting there with the screen on letting anyone see what I am doing.
How can I set it so I can RDP into the Ubuntu box regardless of whether it is locked or the screen has been turned off?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog)

Answer (score 2):

## Install the Extension Manager

To install the Extension Manager app in Ubuntu, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on the remote Ubuntu computer you want to access using RDP and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

You will be prompted for your password. When you type the password the cursor won't move and you won't see `********`. This is normal in the Ubuntu terminal.

## Install the `Allow Locked Remote Desktop` Extension

Open the app **Extension Manager** and within it search for the [Allow Locked Remote Desktop](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4338/allow-locked-remote-desktop/) GNOME extension.

Then install this Gnome extension on the remote computer.

After installing this extension the RDP session won't go black when the remote computer's screen lock kicks in.

Hope this helps