# RDP/VNC black screen when local user is logged in, will not connect when no user is logged in

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

i'm trying to get RDP and/or VNC working with my Unbuntu desktop. Having some weird issues. When the account i have setup is logged in, i am able to RDP or VNC to the machine except i get a black screen. I understand that's normal behavior when the account is already logged in and you try to RDP/VNC to the machine. So then i log out on the machine and attempt to RDP and/or VNC into the machine now that the account is logged out, now i get a failure to connect. Not sure where to go from here, black screen when RDP'ing when a user is logged in, failure to connect when no user is logged in.

Unbuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog)