# How do I read and write to my Ubuntu HDD from my Win10 PC?

Tags: networking, windows, remote-access, remmina

I have a new Ubuntu computer on the same internet network as my primary Windows 10 PC. I do not have a need to Remote Access into the whole Ubuntu PC, but I would love to be able to read and write files from my Windows PC into my backup Ubuntu PC HDD, and vice versa, ideally.

I have tried using Remmina from Ubuntu and RDP from my PC, but cannot seem to connect either way. I have also tried to make the hard drive discoverable on my network, but cannot seem to find it from my PC.

If anyone is able to assist, I would really appreciate it! I'm happy to share more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Comment: Thanks for the share! That did help some, but it didn't solve the problem. I adjusted some sharing settings in the Ubuntu settings and I can now see "will's media on Jeeves" (Jeeves is my Ubuntu comp) on my Windows PC. And I can access a list of 3 folders, Music, Pictures, and Videos. I go to Ubuntu settings to change those to the drives I want to share that I DO have sharing settings activated on, but the folder options to pick from on my Windows PC do not update. Any ideas?

Comment: Please ask a new question with a link to the question that partially worked. And add a contact here so that I know.

Comment: When it comes to using RDP with Ubuntu, you should read these two answers: [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog/1428784#1428784) and [Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless/1409120#1409120)