# Still can't rdp to Ubuntu 22.04 when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen is locked

Tags: login, rdp

While this question already exists in some form, there is no proper answer, I can't comment/reply (as it's "active"), just some workarounds, and none do the right thing:

1. The new RDP doesn't allow you to connect remotely unless you login locally first.
2. xrdp "xrdp does not allow remote connection if you are logged in locally" OR it connects you to a different session.
   Sure, there are workarounds, but why does everything have to be so hard?
   I want to keep the "remote" PC in the basement, be able to remotely connect to it when it's freshly booted or it locked itself, and I want to be able to use same session when I go local as when I use it from upstairs.
   It's so easy with Windows, why so hard in Ubuntu?
   Every few years I try Ubuntu again, only to be disappointed by how hard simple things are.
   Please fix.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site where users ask questions and other users provide answers. Most of us can't fix how Ubuntu works. If you think this is a bug, please file a bug report. Bugs are off topic here and rants are discouraged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog)

Comment: Thank you but I read that before I wrote this.

Comment: I sort of agree ranting is not ideal when long and generic, but one should be able to express displeasure at specific things. Yes, one sentence is rather generic but it's one sentence. If not here, then where? Apparently Canonical has a relationship with AskUbuntu, so one hopes that they may support things when other users can't help.

Comment: Ubuntu developers do not monitor this site for bug reports and feature request. See [How do I report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for more.

Comment: It's not a bug if it does what "they" want it to do. They just can't think of all use cases. They are "pros" and maybe work in "pro" environments, but they promote it to be used by "non-pros" so they should accommodate those needs/wants; I'm not the only one that wants this. Next you're gonna tell me to make a feature request. I might if nobody has a solution.

Comment: Your wish is granted! In a month's time Ubuntu 24.04 will be released. You will be able to log in using RDP and the built in remote access feature.

Comment: That's good news, thank you for letting me know, but I wish it was added to 22.04 LTS, as I often find things break when upgrading. Even now; it seems I have to use an older kernel to avoid some errors on AMD processor. I chose LTS for that reason and am weary about straying. It should be easy (I think) to add that to 22.04 since they obviously "know how to". AND they know it's needed, so it would be pointless to make another feature request for this.