Access Remote Laptop when lid is closed
I have set up a Remmina remote desktop client connection to a laptop on Ubuntu 24.04
It works find as long as the lid is open but when it blanks the screen it can not access it.
The LapTop stays running when lid is closed and because the Screen Lock/Blank screen delay is set to 15 minutes.
I can connect via Remmina for 15 minutes only.
How to set it up correctly.

hope this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog

Your question does not state if the laptop is still running when the lid is closed. Please edit the question and add that info.

This question is similar to: Maintaining RDP connection to Ubuntu after Ubuntu Screen times out (goes black). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
