# How do I connect to an XRDP Session from a different machine

Tags: 22.04, xrdp

I have XRDP Setup on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I want to set it up so as I can connect to the same session from different machines like my desktop and laptop. But also so as I can go to the machine physically and access that same session.

Is this possible?

Comment: Uninstall `xrdp` and use `gnome-remote-desktop` that came with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm looking for a VNC or RDP Ubuntu to Ubuntu setup that logs into current user session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391362/im-looking-for-a-vnc-or-rdp-ubuntu-to-ubuntu-setup-that-logs-into-current-user)